# How to understand the type declaration and definition for List and Vect in Idris lang?

Tags: types, programming-languages, idris, dependent-type

In [Idris doc](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#list-and-vect) there are the following lines:

```
data List a = Nil | (::) a (List a)

data Vect : Nat -> Type -> Type where
   Nil  : Vect Z a
   (::) : a -> Vect k a -> Vect (S k) a
```

I assumed line 1 is a type definition for List and the rest is type declaration for Vect.
I thought there should be both declaration and definition so I looked in the [Idris repo](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev) and found:

```
data List : (elem : Type) -> Type where
  Nil : List elem
  (::) : (x : elem) -> (xs : List elem) -> List elem
```

Which shares a similar pattern with type declaration of Vect so it seems fine. but I cannot find `data List a = Nil | (::) a (List a)` in souce code. Also, I cannot find type definition for Vect.

So, my confusions are:

- Why I can't find `data List a = Nil | (::) a (List a)` in source code?
- What's the actual type definition for Vect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no separate "type definition" and "type declaration" in Idris; these are just two ways to write a type definition. See the [Syntax Guide](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/syntax-guide.html#data-types):

> Idris provides two kinds of syntax for defining data types. The first, Haskell style syntax, defines a regular algebraic data type...
>
> The second, more general kind of data type, is defined using Agda or GADT style syntax. This syntax defines a data type that is parameterised by some values (in the `Vect` example, a value of type `Nat` and a value of type `Type`).

GADTs were introduced by Haskell, and reading e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT or searching for GADT can give you additional explanations of the second style.

The GADT-style definition of `List` is equivalent to the `data List a = ...` one except for allowing to name `elem`, `x`, and `xs`.